# How do I get the 2d sprite gameObject in front of the UI Canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr4wZ.png)

[2d sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfjDm.png)

[panel UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SguP5.png)

[in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAJhG.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Use an Image UI component (right click on canvas object > UI > Image), not a sprite renderer. Those are used for in scene, not UI.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Fist make sure your [canvas' Render Mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html) is not set to `Screen Space - Overlay`.
If it is, then switch it to `Screen Space - Camera` and then change its `Render Camera` property to point to your main camera.

You can then use the following canvas' properties to control where it appears in relation to other sprites (which appears on top of which), the same way you control any other [2D Sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html):

1. `Sorting Layer`
2. `Order in Layer`

Also worth noting that 2D Sprites with same `Sorting Layer` and `Order in Layer` will use the distance to the camera to decide which one appears on top of which, and the same is true for the canvas:

- If your canvas' `Render Mode` is set to `Screen Space - Camera`, it will always be positioned in front of your camera and you need to use its `Plane Distance` property in order to position it correctly.
- If your canvas' `Render Mode` is set to `World Space`, you can position it freely in the world in the same way you position any other sprite.

Answer (score -1):

First of all the hierarchy window in unity is completely irrelevant when its about positioning.

**In Unity everything is 3D, even if you switch to 2D perspective.**

So in your case you still have your camera, your sprite and your canvas in a 3D Dimension.

To set your sprite in front of the canvas you only need to increase the positioning stats (seen in your "panel UI" screenshot) at least slightly closer to your camera than the canvas is.

Comment: It is not completely true that the hierarchy order is irrelevant: the UI elements inside a canvas will be drawn according to the hierarchy. Also your solution will generally not work, as it requires a lot of pre-conditions (only if the canvas is set to world space, and if the sorting layer and sorting order are the same as the sprite render's)